# prevent draggable item to be drop over an other draggable item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I found few post about my question on stackoverflow but none with draggable div droped inside other div.
[This is a good example](http://jsfiddle.net/htWV3/1/)
I would like to prevent the drop of draggable item over an other draggable item.
If true send the item back.

I try with something like this:

```
drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
}
```

It send the item back to the original place but all the time, not if over an other draggable item.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieubujold/Ch8c2/16/)

Comment: @MathieB
You need to reset the revert option to 'invalid' in the stop event.
Also in the "This good example", the author has made the draggable a droppable too. And when another draggable is dropped on this droppable come draggable, the element being dropped is reverted and on when the stop method of the draggable which was dropped is called the revert option is reset. Hope this helps